# Custom module gives error in Magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I created a simple custom module in Magento2. I enabled my module in app/etc/config.php, executed the command bin/magento setup:upgrade in my project root folder and cleared all the cache directories.

But after page refresh, I'm getting the below error page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your module version in two files:

app/code/Eglobe/HelloWorld/etc/module.xml

app/code/Eglobe/HelloWorld/composer.json

and make sure they are the same

Comment: Both versions are same.

Comment: Please try: go to phpmyadmin, remove record with module name is Eglobe_HelloWorld on table setup_module, remove all tables of your module and run bin/magento setup:upgrade again.